# Convert char to smallint SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have column in SQL Server table called `Book_pagenumber` declared as `smallint`. One of page contained the number and letter like 50a when I tried to use insert statement as shown below

```
insert into [Books] (book_id, book_author, Book_pagenumber) 
values (50, 'Test', cast('50a' as smallint))
```

I get an error message

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type smallint

I also used

```
INSERT INTO [Books] (book_id, book_author, Book_pagenumber) 
VALUES (50, 'Test', CAST(CAST('50a' AS VARCHAR(3)) AS SMALLINT)
```

I got the data inserted but just number 50 without the letter.

Please I need advice how to convert char to smallint without changing the column data type

Comment: well...what value of smallint data type should `'50a'` convert to?

Comment: Of course you got an error because 50a is not a valid smallint. I would suggest you need to fix the source of your data to not have crappy input.

Comment: '50a' convert to smallint

Comment: and what value would that be??

Comment: That's what I'm looking for 'I want help with converting without change column datatype

Comment: I need insert '50a' into the table

Comment: jesus man, you want to convert `50a` to a smallint. You can't convert chars to an int, what integer value is `50a` supposed to be?

Comment: You CAN'T insert the string 50a into a smallint. It makes no sense at all. It simply is invalid. You either need to clean up the input source, decide on some substitution rules (like discard any characters that are not 0-9), or accept a NULL because that value is not a smallint.

Comment: Type `int` is a whole number, that is what it can store. Random example values: `13028` or `1` or `-484`. Your problem is that you are trying to convert `50a` to a whole number. If that is still not clear to you think of it this way: If you went to the bank and asked for `50a` dollars, what what the teller give you? Probably just a weird look because `50a` is not a number, you might as well be asking for `abc` dollars or `hello` dollars (which are equally as invalid).

Comment: Thank you guys for helping and clarification

Answer (score 4):

One option could be

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Book_pagenumber varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('50a'),
('123b'),
('175')

Select *
      ,AsInt = try_convert(int,left(Book_pagenumber,patindex('%[^0-9]%',Book_pagenumber+'a')-1))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Book_pagenumber AsInt
50a            50
123b           123
175            175
```

Comment: I'd probably use a patindex of NOT 0-9 instead of a positive match on a-z. Otherwise they'll come back with "this didn't work for `52;c`"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Clearly you thunked harder than I did  :)   I'll make the edit - Thanks

Comment: I would upvote this, but op hasn't make it clear yet that he wants `'50a'` to be `50`

Comment: @Lamak Perhaps a leap in my part, but when I see cast('50a' as smallint) I made the assumption.

Comment: I get it....but then when asking the op, we got "I need insert '50a' into the table" as a reply....that's why I'm waiting before voting

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will clean your string from characters, other than numeric:

```
-- Create Function that will keep only numeric values in @String
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_NumericOnly (@String NVARCHAR(64))
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @Result VARCHAR(5) = N''
        , @Position INT = 1
        , @Length INT;

    SELECT @Length = LEN(@String);

    WHILE (@Position <= @Length)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result += CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@String, @Position, 1) BETWEEN CHAR(48) AND CHAR(57) THEN SUBSTRING(@String, @Position, 1) ELSE N'' END;

        SELECT @Position += 1;
    END

    RETURN @Result;
END
GO

-- Test the Function
INSERT Books (book_id, book_authoer, Book_pagenumber)
SELECT
    50
    , 'Test'
    , dbo.udf_NumericOnly('a4s22df5');
```